# Modal popup shows login page when session's expires

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I display partial view in modal popup through ajax call from controller on edit button click, also my controller is decorated with attribute which checks for session expires or not if session expires it redirects to login page.
It is working fine until i clear the cache and when i click edit button it shows login page in my modal popup.
Following is my Jquery

```
 $('.btnpopupdetails').click(function () {
            var url = "Edit";
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
                $('#ModalPopupContent').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

Filter attribute

```
 public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        string TempEmail = Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Email"]);


        if (TempEmail == "")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Default",
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{
                    {"controller", "Auth"},
                    {"action", "LogOut"},
                    {"returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl}
                    });
        }
```

I don't know how to prevent login page to show in popup. It should redirect to login page.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The ajax call hits the server and the server returns the login page.  Technically this is a redirection, but your browser doesn't know that because ajax has captured the response and then added it to the modal window.

I think what I would do is first make an ajax call that allows me to check if the session is expired, if it is then in the ajax success method I would redirect them to the login page else display the modal if the session is still active.

Comment: I tried but problem is i have decorated my controller with attribute which checks for session and i redirect to logout page from that attribute only so it does not call my custom action inside the controller which checks for session. I think i need to do some changes in my attribute.